# Using align* inside a newly defined environment

Tags: align, environments

I would like to take this :

```
\newenvironment{myfind}[1]
{{\em Find : #1}\begin{eqnarray*}}{\end{eqnarray*}}

\begin{myfind} {$\lim_{x \to -1} f(x)$}
    \lim_{x \to -1^+} f(x)&=+\infty \\
    \lim_{x \to -1^-} f(x)&=+\infty \\ \\
    \therefore \lim_{x \to -1} f(x)&=+\infty
\end{myfind}
```

and use align* instead, however if I do it breaks, the tags don't match the align starts but doesn't find the closing align* .

Now it isn't a huge deal, just curious why it happens and is it still possible to use align* vs eqnarray*.

Comment: I am not an expert at this, someone else may be able to provide a more rigorous answer. Basically, the mechanism of some commands/environments dictates that they **cannot be the argument of other commands** (e.g. [verbatim commands](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin)). This is highly implementation-related, which means there does not exist a universal standard.

Comment: The main issue is that the `align*` environment is set to process its argument twice, first to measure the widths of various lines, then to perform the actual typesetting job. During the first pass, `align*` searches ahead and looks for `\end{align*}`. It will come across `\end{myfind}`, but that will not yet have been expanded to `\end{align*}`. Eventually LaTeX will crash as it never locates the relevant `\end{align*}` statement.